# Adding license agreement for Installshield prerequisites

Tags: installshield-2010

Can any one tell me how add License agreement for before installing prerequisites in installshield 2010.

Comment: What is the project type? MSI, Installscript, or Installscript-MSI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want, you can move your prerequisite as as "Feature Prerequisite". The feature prerequisite is tied to a specific feature on your product. You can then update your License Agreement to include any information with regards to your prerequisite.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to not install the programs as prerequisites, but launch them directly from your UI? After the dialog that displays the license agreement, have a custom dialog that displays the status of the other installers. Use the LaunchAppAndWait method to execute the other installers.

Comment: But I have 4 prerequisites 
1.Dot.net franework 3.5 sp1 
2.ADO.net Hotfix.
3.SQL server 2005 sp1 
4.visal c++ redistribute.

Befrore installing I need to check the registy and after I have install.

But as you said through LaunchAppAndWait is that possible, can you give me some code snippets.

That would be grate.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know that this is possible. By definition, the prereqs run before any of the UI.

Comment: Is their any way like adding using any script file to bring the license agreement I need to show license agreement for microsoft related prerequisites.